# Azure Machine Learning + R: Reading files

Tags: r, import, azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to run my R-code in the Azure Machine Learning environment, and I am running into a dead end trying to import data from the blob storage.

Locally I can easily import a file like this:

```
data <- read.delim("myfile.xls", sep = "\t", skip = 9)
```

When I am using Azure machine learning, just referring to file in the blob storage location, I get the error "cannot open the connection".

```
data <- read.delim("https://knnstorage.blob.core.windows.net/knn/myfile.xls", sep = "\t", skip = 9)
```

I have additionally attempted to import the file using the "Import Data" option, but it only allows one to import csv files or excel-files with at the most one line to be skipped.

In the future I will also need to import unstructured text into Azure Machine Learning. Is this really not possible using R?

Comment: I ended up not going any further with this lackluster service.

Comment: Check if this file publicly accessible. You might consider using the [Import Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio/import-data#import-from-online-data-sources) module.

Comment: We decided that the tool is too limited for our uses, so we haven't been following its developments.